# What happens to SE images on Imgur that we post but don't use?

Tags: discussion

I use the SE Uploader palette to upload images, eg: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jncBA.png. I'm going to upload a different image. Can we remove something we put up? Do we need to worry about that?

Comment: [Relevant meta.SO discussion.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94710)

Comment: @J.M. Oh.Thanks.

Comment: I asked about this once and I've been told that they are not automatically cleaned up (but of course someone might decide to do a manual cleanup in the future).

Comment: I always appreciate feedback about the image uploader palette and how people use it.  I was considering adding a button to upload to `imgur.com` instead of `stack.imgur.com` for personal use, and to avoid people using `stack.imgur.com` for personal (non-SE-related) uploads.  Do you think this is necessary, based on how you use the palette?